# How to get posts that have certain meta key value and order based on another meta key's value

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, query

Here is the code I gathered off the internet so far:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '5000',
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'is_part_of_series' => array(
            'key'     => 'epic-series-select-series',
            'value' => $series_id,
            'compare' => '=',
        ), 
        'chapter_order' => array(
            'key'     => 'epic-series-chapter-number',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'chapter_order' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
```

but for some reason, this gets the correct 3 posts plus some other posts - which I have no idea why are present. I checked the meta table in `MySQL` and only the correct 3 posts have the meta key with the value I am querying. Apparently, I am doing something wrong in the query! Any ideas?

I tried asking `ChatGPT` for help but it did not.

EDIT 1:

Here is a screenshot of the only posts that have `epic-series-select-series` meta key: [image]

Comment: noting that what you're doing does not scale well with post meta as the post meta table is not optimised for searches/filtering, if you changed the `is_part_of_series` post meta into a `series` taxonomy it would provide _enormous_ performance improvements and speed ups. Also `5000` is a very very high number of posts, for reference the REST API limits to 100 max and Yoast SEO uses 1k as an upper limit for a limited query and a lot of sites struggle with that. Can you share the values you're searching for and their format?

Comment: The `$series_id` I am searching for is `32881`

Comment: I've also added a screenshot with all posts having that meta key.

Comment: Can you point me to a good resource on how to do it with taxonomies if you know any?

Comment: other than the official developer docs and searching this site i'm not sure what to suggest, this stack isn't set up for recommending external sources and we actively discourage it. I would note that taxonomies and post types don't need to be user/public facing

Comment: What do you mean by public facing?

Comment: Public facing is not a technical term, open to the world, viewable by external users, e.g. a photo in your window pointed outwards is public facing, a photo pointed inwards is not. posts tags and categories are public facing, they have archives templates REST API endpoints RSS feeds and URLs, and can be seen by the public. Nav menu taxonomies are not, and do not have URLs/archives/templates, and most people are unaware that taxonomy event exists as its admin UI is hidden and a custom menu UI was built.

Comment: What I did not explain in my question is that $series_id by which I am searching is pointing towards a custom post type called `series`, is it possible to connect custom taxonomy to this `series`? I've been reading about taxonomies but haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Comment: while you could use post IDs as slugs in a hidden/private taxonomy, or you could assign the taxonomy to both post types and look up which series are also in that term, there are many ways to do it, but it looks like your posts only have a single series ID and that post parent may be a much easier faster solution

Comment: Can that be done with the default posts I read that they are not hierarchical?

Comment: I guess I can just create a plugin that sets `parent_post` to whatever I want?

Comment: wether a post type is hierarchical is a runtime memory thing, the database itself has no concept of non-hierarchy, so you can set the parent of a post that is non-hierarchical